# Ruby equivalent to C# Console.ReadKey()?

Tags: c#, ruby

Becoming an intermediate Rubyist as of late, so I've been writing simple Ruby console programs to run in the `irb`.

I've made a decent of amount of console programs in C#, and I was curious if there's any method in Ruby by default or in a gem that does the same thing/is similar to C#'s Console.ReadKey? I know of the [FFI gem's](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/windows-examples) `keybd_event` method, but that seems a little a bit much for simple programs.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ whether you expect to receive an input from _rubyists_, you should describe the expected behaviour rather than referring it “similar to C#'s `Console.ReadKey`.”

Answer (score 1):

There is [`IO#getc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-getc) used for that purpose. But please be aware of that the console might have an input buffering, preventing your code from receiving a char immediately. Flush might required (e. g. <kbd>⏎</kbd>,) or a direct low-level `stty` setting, depending on what you need to accomplish.

Here is [an example provided by Matz himself](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/2999):

> That' what UNIX getc is by default.  You can:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/ruby   
> begin
>   system("stty raw -echo")
>   str = STDIN.getc
> ensure
>   system("stty -raw echo")
> end
> p str
> ```

---

There is also a gem [`HighLine`](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) providing that functionality:

```
require "highline/system_extensions"
include HighLine::SystemExtensions

c = get_character
print c.chr
```

Comment: Fantastic! I had recent installed the `highline` gem. Thank you.